# how to refresh the page after fadeOut function in my script?

Tags: jquery, html

how to refresh the page after the fadeOut effect occurred/happened  ?
here's what i have at the moment,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'classes/ajax.login.php',
    data: "username=" +username+ "&password="+password,
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg == 'success'){
            $('div#login').fadeOut('normal');

        } else {
            alert(msg);
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add it as callback

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'classes/ajax.login.php',
    data: "username=" +username+ "&password="+password,
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg == 'success'){
            $('div#login').fadeOut('normal', function(){
                     document.location.href = this.location.href
            });

        } else {
            alert(msg);
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: what to add in order to refresh the page ?

Comment: @sasori: document.location.href = this.location.href

Comment: none of them worked :(  , `$('body').append('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">');` , i even tried $('head')

Comment: problem solved document.location.href = location.href + '?_=' + Math.random();